# moving a view under finger

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view-chain; the first view is in the second, the second is in the third and so on.
I want to move the top most view under my finger and I did some logics to handle this in touchesBegan:touchesMoved:...
The problem is that each view has different gestures and if I try to move the top most view, the views behind it also respond to the moving. Is there any way to disable the gesture except the top most view when I am trying to move it?

Also I do not want the top most view to go outside the border of its immediate parent view, and I did some logics in the touchesMoved: to reset the center or the top-most view. The effect is not good as this approach allows the view to go outside, but will move it back once it went out.

Comment: You say, "when I am trying to move it". How will you indicate when you are trying to move it?

Answer (score 1):

How about just creating and turning on a disable flag at the bottom views while adding the top most view to it's parent view, if you don't want the bottom views to respond to their own gesture recognisers?

Comment: yes, this is one solution, but I found it is easier to use pangesture rather than touchesbegain methods